# Keeps getting &Python Path was unexpect at this time error in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, python3, virtualenv

This issue happening starting from today when I was doing some coding in Python in Visual Studio Code. I usually develop my program in a virtual environment, but today for some reason, when I tried to execute selection of codes, I kept getting "& was unexpected at this time". I tried Google the issue but doesn't seem a lot of people encounter the issue before.

Additional detail:
I am using Python 3.7.2 64-bit.
I am activating my environment using Windows Command Prompt.
Creating my virtual environment using the Venv module.
My VS Code version is 1.34.0.

I have attached a screenshot.
[VS Code Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zHRP.png)

Comment: You are running a command prompt not a python interpretor ...

Answer (score 0):

turns out it was the issue with latest version of the Microsoft Python extension. I rolled back to the previous version and that fixed the issue.